# Send a post to PHP with jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two pages. The first page is sending events, and in the second page I want to receive the event and echo them.

But it doesn't work.

#### First page

```
<form method="post" action="answer.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="exam pull-left">
                <?php
                //           <?php
                // input1, input2, input3, input4
                while($queryFetched = $FetchedEdit->fetch_assoc()){?>
                    <h5><?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?> - <?php echo $queryFetched['question'];?></h5>
                    <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input1'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input1'];?><br>
                    <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input2'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input2'];?><br>
                    <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input3'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input3'];?><br>
                    <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input4'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input4'];?><br>
                    <br><hr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sauces" value="sub" name="submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myRadio').click(function(e){
            var answer =  ($(this).val());
            $.post("answer.php",{
                question: answer
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Second page

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['question']))
{
    $name = $_POST['question'];
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) You don't have a success callback for your `$.post`

Comment: define "doesn't work" Quite possibly it echoes the values, but since you never use the response sent back by the server from your ajax call, you can't see it. Follow the advice in the comment above and use the tools at your disposal to check what's actually happening. Also consider adding a callback to the ajax call so you can receive the response in your page and make use of it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you are planning to send value of radio button onselect, what's the need of your FORM? Anyway I've posted below both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax call back functions like success, error ,complete to trace the errors. Refer below code for reference.

```
$.post("demo_test_post.php",
{
    name: "Donald Duck",
    city: "Duckburg"
},
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are planning to send data to `answer.php` without FORM SUBMIT, via AJAX.

Include this in your `head`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Your `form`

```
<form method="post" action="answer.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="exam pull-left">
                <?php
                    while($queryFetched = $FetchedEdit->fetch_assoc()){?>
                        <h5><?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?> - <?php echo $queryFetched['question'];?></h5>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input1'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input1'];?><br>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input2'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input2'];?><br>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input3'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input3'];?><br>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input4'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input4'];?><br>
                        <br><hr>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>

                //****** Change input type to 'button'
                <input type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-sauces" value="sub" name="submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and you `scripts`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myRadio').click(function () {
            var answer = $("input[name='name']:checked").val();
            //console.log(answer);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'answer.php',
                data: { question: answer },
                success: function () {
                  alert('Radio was submitted');
                }
          });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Your `answer.php` page

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['question'];
    echo $name;
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

**OR**

IF submitting via FORM SUBMIT

Your `form`

```
<form method="post" action="answer.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="exam pull-left">
                <?php
                    while($queryFetched = $FetchedEdit->fetch_assoc()){?>
                        <h5><?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?> - <?php echo $queryFetched['question'];?></h5>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input1'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input1'];?><br>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input2'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input2'];?><br>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input3'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input3'];?><br>
                        <input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="name<?php echo $queryFetched['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $queryFetched['input4'];?>"><?php echo $queryFetched['input4'];?><br>
                        <br><hr>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>

                //****** Change input type to 'submit'
                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="SUBMIT FORM" name="submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Your `answer.php` page

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['name']))   //******* Radio name
        {
            echo "You have selected :".$_POST['name'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
```